# How to get data from Amazon RDS using a Lambda function in Node.js?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a database in Aurora PostgreSQL and I’m using an API Gateway to invoke the Lambda functions made in Node.js for the APIs. Here is my code for a simple GET request with no URL parameters:

```
var pg = require("pg");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var conn = “//Connection string";
    var client = new pg.Client(conn);
    client.connect();

    //var id = event.id;
    console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');
    var query = client.query("SELECT * from USERS;");
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log(jsonString);
        client.end();
        context.succeed(jsonObj);
    });
};
```

I am able to get all the records from this table successfully. What changes must I make to the code and to the API Gateway itself to make a GET request with a parameter for a WHERE clause to select a specific user from their username, and a POST request to insert new users into the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **proxy lambda integration**, all the GET and POST parameters submitted into the API Gateway will be available in in the `event` object. Thus, you have to get the values submitted for `WHERE` and `INSERT` from the event.

The `event` structure is shown in:

- [Input format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

You will also need to ensure correct return data from the lambda. **Return data also requires proper format**:

- [Output format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Comment: I have tried to follow the documentation and hence enabled proxy integration to be able to tap the event object. I then get an “internal server error” with the message: ```Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses.```. Am I doing it right? Because without proxy integration the event object appears to be blank {}.

Comment: @NoohAhamad You could make new question with the relevant details, lambda code and error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can code your Lambda function to connect to a RDS database. Now when you do this, there are some things to consider.

1. You need to configure your Lambda function to use the same VPC as the security group that RDS is using. This is discussed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html.
2. Next from your Lambda function, you still have to set a connection to the database. How this is done is dependent on the programming language that you are using. For example, if you are using the Lambda Java runtime API, you can use a Java connection. See below.

Once you do this - you can connect to RDS and perform SQL statements. This makes it possible to write Lambda functions that can query data from RDS and then use that Lambda function within a larger cloud based workflow using AWS Step Functions.

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
    
public class ConnectionHelper {
    
    private String url;
    private static ConnectionHelper instance;
   
    private ConnectionHelper() {
            url = "jdbc:mysql://formit.xxxxxxshym6k.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb?useSSL=false";
        }
    
        public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new ConnectionHelper();
            }
            try {
    
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                return DriverManager.getConnection(instance.url, "root","root1234");
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static void close(Connection connection) {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is asking about nodejs. That would be in javascript, not java. Please update your answer to say this explicitly

Answer (score 1):

> **Accessing table data from RDS using lambda function with encrypted key (KMS) and Environment variable**

**Step 1 :-** First Enable key in KMS(Key Management Service (KMS))
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Review your key Policy and Done! with KMS creation

```
{
"Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User1@gmail.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Create*",
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:Enable*",
            "kms:List*",
            "kms:Put*",
            "kms:Update*",
            "kms:Revoke*",
            "kms:Disable*",
            "kms:Get*",
            "kms:Delete*",
            "kms:TagResource",
            "kms:UntagResource",
            "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
            "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User1@gmail.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User2@gmail.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User3@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User1.dilip@gmail.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User2@gmail.com",
                "arn:aws:iam::163806924483:user/User3@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

[image]

**Step:- 2** Create a policy in IAM for KMS assign to ur each lambda function

```
"StringEquals": {
            "kms:EncryptionContext:LambdaFunctionName": [
                "LambdaFunction-1",
                "LambdaFunction-2",
                "LambdaFunction-3"
            ]
        }
```

[image]

**Step 3:-** Assign a Policy created in Step-2 to ur default lambda Role(1st Lambda need to be created to get default lambda role)
[image]

**Step 4:-**  Create lambda Function

**Node.js** Code for lambda Function

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const aws = require("aws-sdk");


const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME;
let res;
let response={};
exports.handler = async(event) => {
reset_globals();

// load env variables
const rds_user = await kms_decrypt(process.env.RDS_USERNAME);
const rds_pwd = await kms_decrypt(process.env.RDS_PASSWORD)

// setup rds connection
var db_connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    user: rds_user,
    password: rds_pwd,
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
    database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

var sqlQuery = `SELECT doc_id from documents`;
await getValues(db_connection,sqlQuery);

}

async function getValues(db_connection,sql) {
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db_connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            response = {statusCode: 500, body:{message:"Database Connection Failed", 
             error: err}};
            console.log(response);
            resolve();
        }
        else {
           
            console.log("Number of records retrieved: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            res = result;
           
            resolve();
        }
    });
    });
}

async function kms_decrypt(encrypted) {
const kms = new aws.KMS();
const req = { CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64'), EncryptionContext: { 
LambdaFunctionName: functionName } };
const decrypted = await kms.decrypt(req).promise();
let cred = decrypted.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
return cred;
}


function reset_globals() {
res = (function () { return; })();
response = {};
}
```

Now u should see KMS in Lambda.
[image]

**Step 5:-** Set Environment Variable and encrypt it.

Lambda ->Functions -> Configuration -> Environment Variable -> Edit

RDS_DATABASE    docrds

RDS_HOSTNAME    docrds-library.c1k3kcldebmp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

RDS_PASSWORD    root123

RDS_PORT        3306

RDS_USERNAME    admin

[image]

In Lambda Function to decrypt the encrypted environment variabled use below code

```
function kms_decrypt(encrypted) {
const kms = new aws.KMS();
const req = { CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64'), EncryptionContext: { 
LambdaFunctionName: functionName } };
const decrypted = await kms.decrypt(req).promise();
let cred = decrypted.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
return cred;
}
```

My RDS document table looks like:-

[image]

I am accessing column doc_id using sqlQuery  in lambda function

```
var sqlQuery = `SELECT doc_id from documents`;
```

After testing the lambda function, I get below output.

[image]

If u gets SQL import Error, then can must add a layer.

[image]

```
errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'\nRequire stack:\n- 
/var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
 "trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'",
```

> You can configure your Lambda function to use additional code and
> content in the form of layers. A layer is a ZIP archive that contains
> libraries, a custom runtime, or other dependencies. With layers, you
> can use libraries in your function without needing to include them in
> your deployment package.
>
> To include libraries in a layer, place them in the directory structure
> that corresponds to your programming language.
>
> Node.js – nodejs/node_modules
>
> Python – python
>
> Ruby – ruby/gems/2.5.0
>
> Java – java/lib

First create a zip archieve that contain mysql archieve.

> First create a folder with name same as lambda function in any react-project . Let say for example:- mkdir lambda-function
>
> Then in terminal $project-path > lambda-function-folder > **# npm init**
>
> Then $project-path > lambda-function-folder > **# npm install mysql**
>
> You should see **node_modules** folder created.
>
> Create another folder name **nodejs** inside lambda-function-folder [**mkdir nodejs**]
>
> Move the **node_modules** inside **nodejs** folder
>
> Zip nodejs folder [**nodejs.zip**] and upload on layer as shown below.
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Then, Goto Lambda--> Layer-->Create layer.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]